# How do I test a google cloud function that uses a storage upload to trigger?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

It's exceptionally slow to test this by uploading files. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can use postman, and add a unit Test: 
 
  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my development and testing, I capture one of the messages that triggers Cloud Functions. These messages are just JSON, so save it to a file and then send back to the function.

Usually, I develop my code locally and run at my desktop. Then I use tools such as `curl` to call my code. Once I have completed development and testing, I move to the cloud and use the same tools to call the Cloud Functions endpoint using Stackdriver to log messages to.

Comment: Create batch script files so that you can execute over and over.

Comment: could you please share any Documentation link that finely define the way you have mentioned above.It will be great help for beginners like us